# Magento - what determines home page layout?

Tags: magento

I have a magento installation.
In CMS pages I have two entries with URL keys:

```
home_en
home_page_sp
```

These seem to govern the entire front page.
Each one is for a specific Store View.
Both use 3-colums layout

My Question: Where do I look to see which store is attached to which page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the configuration value set at

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages -> CMS Home Page
```

This setting determines which CMS page Magento will load for the homepage.  Use the store switcher in the upper left hand corner to determine what value is set at what level.  (The labels for the drop down are the page title, but the option values are the actual `home_en`/`home_page_sp` codes).

Comment: geez. I must have known that because I set it up at soem point!!

Comment: @george Yeah, it's not like Magento have 8554 other different things to remember.

Comment: Alan - love your tutorials BTW!